# Silverlight application on legacy infrastructure? IIS 6 IE 6 .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, silverlight, iis-6, ria

I'm currently looking at the possibility of using silverlight for a portal style application for a big corperate.

The application is internal and 70% of the users are running IE6 and the chance of them upgrading is non-existent for a while (that's the way corporates roll)..

I know that silverlight runs fine in IE6 so from that angle were covered but it appears that you require .NET 4.0 to use the RIA services and entity framework to push data back and forth from silverlight on the client to the server..

This application needs to be hosted on a private (somewhat legacy) server which is runnning IIS 6 and currently running .NET 2.0..

Whats the best route for me to take?

Is it possible to run .NET 4.0 and RIA behind IIS 6?

Is there another way to do this without updating anything on the server?

Would i be better off firing XML or JSON back and forth from a .NET 2.0 application?

Thanks very much

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run .Net 4 and RIA from IIS 6.  You can also install .Net 4 along side .Net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 without any conflicts.

You can call vanilla asmx or wcf services from Silverlight, but WCF RIA makes life much easier.

Comment: Thanks @Geoff one thing ive been hearing is that IIS 6 doesn't let you *run* multiple versions of the .NET framework like you can one per pool in IIS 7.. is this true? i'm really nervous about messing with that server cause theres a massively mission critical app runnning on it and it's a physical server so no snapshots etc..

Comment: @Daniel - No that is not true.  I have a couple dozen applications as virtual directories under a single web site.  Some are 2.0, and some are 4.0.

Comment: @Daniel:  You would be creating a new app pool to host the services side of this application.  Of course a large corporation with "massively critical applications" will have test images of the server to play with right?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones haha.. you'd be suprised man ;) they do have a UAT / Test server which is better than nothing but no images of that specific server config per se.. i'm installing a vanilla copy of WS2003 in a vm on my laptop and trying to match the config as best as possible at the moment.. will let ya know how it go's!

Comment: @AnthonyWJones oh i'm just a contractor by the way.. not my company ;)